# Extending protobuf.FieldOptions in imported .proto file

Tags: c++, protocol-buffers

I'm trying to define my custom field option in google protocol buffers. If I create such a file, everything works ok:

```
import "google/protobuf/descriptor.proto";

package tutorial;

extend google.protobuf.FieldOptions {
  optional int32 myopt = 70000;
}

message Persona {
  required string name = 1 [(myopt)=5];
}
```

However, if I try to move "myopt" definition to another file, compilation fails:

**myext.proto:**

```
package myext;

import "google/protobuf/descriptor.proto";

extend google.protobuf.FieldOptions {
  optional int32 myopt = 70000;
}
```

**addressbook.proto:**

```
import "google/protobuf/descriptor.proto";
import "myext.proto";

package tutorial;


message Persona {
  required string name = 1 [(myopt)=5];
}
```

**compilation:**

```
$ protoc --cpp_out=. -I/usr/include -I. addressbook.proto
addressbook.proto:8:29: Option "(myopt)" unknown.
```

Is there any way to define custom field options in other file than the one that use it? It is important to move common part to a common file if I want to use my option in several .proto files.

Comment: If I use "(myext.myopt)" instead of "(myopt)" everything is ok.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you've made a new package with your new proto file, you'll need to reference the package's namespace.

As you noted in your comment, just use "(myext.myopt)" instead of "(myopt)", so it looks like this:

### myext.proto:

Unmodified from what you showed

```
package myext;

import "google/protobuf/descriptor.proto";

extend google.protobuf.FieldOptions {
  optional int32 myopt = 70000;
}
```

### addressbook.proto:

Replace "(myopt)" with "(myext.myopt)"

```
import "google/protobuf/descriptor.proto";
import "myext.proto";

package tutorial;


message Persona {
  required string name = 1 [(myext.myopt)=5];
}
```

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I wrote in the comment :)

Answer (score 1):

Because you have a package **myext**

you should be doing

```
import "myext/myext.proto";
```

with myext.proto located in a **sub-directory** of **myext**.

In protocol buffer package indicates the directory where the file should reside (like in java)

Comment: It doesn't solve the problem. However, you gave me a hint that "package" has some influence here, and it lead to a true resolution (see comment on my question).

Comment: This answer is incorrect.  The package name declared in the `.proto` file need not have anything to do with the directory structure.  They commonly match, but this is only by convention, not a requirement.