# Proto file dependency on other proto files

Tags: c++, protocol-buffers

Experts:

I have two .proto files (shown below), the second one has a dependency on the first one.

**ImageMessage.proto:**

```
package dvr;

message ImageMessage {
    required int32 width = 1;
    required int32 height = 2;
    required int32 type = 3;
    repeated bytes data = 4;
}
```

**DvrMessage.Proto:**

```
package dvr;

import "ImageMessage.proto";

message DvrMessage {
    required ImageMessage firstImage = 1;
    required ImageMessage secondImage = 2;
}
```

When I try to compile them as shown here:

```
protoc --cpp_out=TestProtoc/generated dvrMessage.proto
```

I receive the following error:

```
dvrMessage.proto:6:14: "ImageMessage" is not defined.
dvrMessage.proto:7:14: "ImageMessage" is not defined.
```

I'm importing it.  What else do I need to do?

Comment: Which file is named what?

Comment: Both files are on the same directory ?

Comment: Yes.  Both files are located in the same directory in the same project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I knew it!!!  The minute I post a question, the answer comes.  I found a hint in [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17126230/extending-protobuf-fieldoptions-in-imported-proto-file).  Sure enough, I looked at all the .proto files and there was a typo in the package definition for the ImageMessage.proto file.

I hope this helps somebody else.  Thank you.